# Trying to fetch the data from server using get and trying to utilize it in a dropdown box in Angular component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I tried to iterate through Object using `*ngFor` but it didn't work. Then I tried to iterate by taking array under the object, the data was shown as expected  but in the console I am still seeing the error:

> Cannot read property 'Types' of undefined

Please help me on this.

**TS**

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.http
      .get('http://localhost:3000/api/types')
      .pipe(
        map(responseData => {

          return responseData;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(posts => {
        // ...
        this.types = posts;
        console.log(posts);
      });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="select-list">
    <label for="Type" class="required" >Type</label>
       <select   name="Type"  id="Type" placeholder = "Select a Type" [(ngModel)] = "type">
          <option *ngFor = "let opptype of types.Types">{{ opptype.type }}</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

**Object retrieved through get**

```
Object
Types: Array(4)
0: {_id: "5eaeecf8fea39a54d4f4eddd", type: "New"}
1: {_id: "5eaeed37fea39a54d4f4ee01", type: "Pending"}
2: {_id: "5eaeed48fea39a54d4f4ee12", type: "Approved"}
3: {_id: "5eaeed64fea39a54d4f4ee28", type: "Rejected"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
message: "Types fetched successfully!"
__proto__: Object
```

**Adding Image of the Dropdown results that are being displayed**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your html as

```
<div class="select-list">
    <label for="Type" class="required" >Type</label>
       <select   name="Type"  id="Type" placeholder = "Select a Type" [(ngModel)] = "type">
          <option *ngFor = "let opptype of types?.Types">{{ opptype.type }}</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

now it will check `.Types` only if there is data in `types`

Answer (score 1):

Root cause of the issue: The View is getting rendered before your api can populate types variable and meanwhile since the api has not returned your types, the variable 'types' seems to be getting set as undefined.

There are 2 scenarios that I see can fix this issue:

1. When you declare the types variable in your component, initialise it to an empty array.

   ```
   this.types = [];
   ```
2. Declare types variable as an Observable and rather use an async pipe in the view. This way Angular will know, that it should expect an asynchronous data for this variable and you can avoid this error i.e. IE will wait for api to populate the variable.

**TS**

```
    types: Observable<any>;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.types = this.http
      .get('http://localhost:3000/api/types')
      .pipe(
        map(responseData => {

          return responseData;
         })
      );
     }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="select-list">
<label for="Type" class="required" >Type</label>
   <select   name="Type"  id="Type" placeholder = "Select a Type" [(ngModel)] = "type">
      <option *ngFor = "let opptype of types.Types | async">{{ opptype.type }}</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, made it asynchronous by adding types?.Types

Answer (score 0):

That's because the time your page is rendered the datas haven't yet been fetched. Best option is to use async.

In your TS file :

```
export interface Types {
    _id: string,
    Type: string
}
...
public types Observable<Types[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.types = this.http.get<Types[]>(‘http://localhost:3000/api/types');
}
```

In your template file :

```
<option *ngFor = "let opptype of types | async">{{ opptype.type }}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, made it asynchronous by adding types?.Types

Comment: No, httpClient get is an asynchronous method returning an observable. You just specify to the template that your variable types is fetched with an asynchronous method with the pipe async after the name of the variable types. NgFor will then wait for the variable to be fetched before trying to loop for it's content.

Answer (score 0):

> I think your error is occure in ts.. please change this.types = posts; to  this.types = posts.Types;

because the datas are occure in ' Types ' array.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.http
      .get('http://localhost:3000/api/types')
      .pipe(
        map(responseData => {

          return responseData;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(posts => {
        // ...
        this.types = posts.Types;
        console.log(this.types);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, made it asynchronous by adding types?.Types